# Clarification on the theorem "no function to map A onto its power set P(A)"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the proof of the theorem "For any set A, there does not exist a function mapping A onto its power set P(A)", there's a sentence (highlighted) that I couldn't follow. Contrary to what the illustration says, clearly B {1, 3} comes from elements of A {1, 2, 3}. Was it a typo or I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map is given as a list of individual relations "[element of $A$] ${}\rightarrow{}$ [subset of $A$]".  So, $\{2\}$ comes from $1$, and so on.  There is no "$\{1,3\}$" in the image of the map, so there is no element of $A$ for that subset to come from (as an image of the map).

Comment: Ahhh. I see. Thanks for the clarification.